# CSS make sidebar fixed when scrolling BUT scrollable when hover on top

Tags: css

I found many explanations online about how to make a **sidebar fixed**, but I'm having an issue when the content of the sidebar is longer than the screen can display.

Is there a way to make the sidebar **"fixed" yet "scrollable"** if you hover on top?

EDIT: I'm adding the jfiddle as an example. Thx

```css
html,body{height:100%}
.wrap{width:100%;height:100%;position:relative}
.head{height:100px;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%}
.bodywrap{margin-top:100px;}
.right{width:200px;top: 100px; bottom: 0px;position: fixed;}
.center,.right,.bodywrap{height:100%}
.right{right:0}
.right{background-color:#ccc}
.head{background-color:#777}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
    <div class='head'>Header</div>
    <div class='bodywrap'>
        <div class='right'>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br>right<br></div>
        <div class='center'>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br>content center div scolls<br> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share some code

Comment: Sure, but without any code we're just guessing to your situation.

Comment: Sorry I must have been distracted... I've now added a sample code. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make it scrollable by setting the sidebar (`.right`) its overflow to: `overflow-y: scroll;`.

Thus,

```
.right {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep! that did the trick nicely... [thumbs up] ;-)

Comment: The problem with this one is that you now have got 2 different scrollbars, one for scrolling the sidebar and another one for the main content